# Bring the data from Matrix table to Rows grouped by Date

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, metadata

I have a data set which looks like this, these are basically profit on 10, 11 and 12

```
Item            10/11             11/11            12/11
    A                30               12                 10
    B                10                5                 15
    C                5                25                 10
    D                15               10                 18
```

and another data frame:

```
Date       Item        A.unit       B.Unit    C.Unit      D.Unit   
10/11       A,D          5            0         0          12
11/11       A,B,C       10            10        5          0
12/11       A           20             0        0           0
```

The unit sold in table 2 can be any value
Now i want the planed profit columns for A, B, C and D from table 1, so that output should like this.

```
Date       Item        A.unit    A.Profit   B.Unit  B.Profit  C.Unit     C.Profit   D.Unit      D.Profit 
10/11       A,D          5          30          0     10         0         5           12            15
11/11       A,B,C       10           12         10     5         5         25           0            10
12/11       A           20          10           0     15        0         10            0           18
```

Can anyone please help me out how to get these two tables data in the final one.

Comment: making a new column called A.Profit and copying the values from the first row of the ITEM after transposing them could be one way.

Answer (score 1):

Solution if `Item` in first `df1` is not index and `Date` in second is not index:

```
print (df1.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=4, step=1)

print (df2.index)
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

Create index by `Item`, transpose and [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) first, then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and last sorting by values of third columns before `.`:

```
df11 = df1.set_index('Item').T.add_suffix('.Profit')
df = df2.merge(df11, left_on='Date', right_index=True).reset_index()

cols = sorted(df.columns[2:], key=lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
df = df[df.columns[:2].tolist() + cols]
print (df)
    Date   Item  A.unit  A.Profit  B.Unit  B.Profit  C.Unit  C.Profit  D.Unit  \
0  10/11    A,D       5        30       0        10       0         5      12   
1  11/11  A,B,C      10        12      10         5       5        25       0   
2  12/11      A      20        10       0        15       0        10       0   

   D.Profit  
0        15  
1        10  
2        18
```

If first columns are indices:

```
print (df1.index)
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object', name='Item')

print (df2.index)
Index(['10/11', '11/11', '12/11'], dtype='object', name='Date')

df11 = df1.T.add_suffix('.Profit')
df = df2.merge(df11, left_index=True, right_index=True).reset_index()

cols = sorted(df.columns[2:], key=lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
df = df[df.columns[:2].tolist() + cols]
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202717/discussion-on-answer-by-jezrael-bring-the-data-from-matrix-table-to-rows-grouped).

Answer (score 0):

```
newdf = pd.concat([df1.transpose(), df2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

#### source data

```
dd1 = {'10/11': {'A': 30, 'B': 10, 'C': 5, 'D': 15},
       '11/11': {'A': 12, 'B': 5, 'C': 25, 'D': 10},
       '12/11': {'A': 10, 'B': 15, 'C': 10, 'D': 18}}

dd2 = {'Item': {'10/11': 'A,D', '11/11': 'A,B,C', '12/11': 'A'},
       'A.unit': {'10/11': 5, '11/11': 10, '12/11': 20},
       'B.Unit': {'10/11': 0, '11/11': 10, '12/11': 0},
       'C.Unit': {'10/11': 0, '11/11': 5, '12/11': 0},
       'D.Unit': {'10/11': 12, '11/11': 0, '12/11': 0}}

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dd2)

df1
Out[1]:

    10/11   11/11   12/11
 A    30    12      10
 B    10    5       15
 C    5     25      10
 D    15    10      18


df2
Out[2]:

        Item    A.unit  B.Unit  C.Unit  D.Unit
  10/11 A,D        5    0       0       12
  11/11 A,B,C     10    10      5       0
  12/11 A         20    0       0       0
```

#### processing data

```
df2.merge(df1.T.rename(columns = {c: str(c)+'.Profit' for c in df1.T.columns}), left_index = True, right_index = True)

Out[3]:

           Item   A.unit    B.Unit  C.Unit  D.Unit  A.Profit    B.Profit    C.Profit    D.Profit
Date                                    
10/11   A,D     5       0       0       12       30         10          5           15
11/11   A,B,C   10      10      5       0        12         5           25          10
12/11   A       20      0       0       0        10         15          10          18
```

Comment: i am getting this error while executing "unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'"- @Alexey

Comment: i have updated code. Looks you columns name type are int. So i put str(c). could you check it again?

Comment: Hi @Alexey still i am not getting correct values, only blank table is coming with total 156 columns, columns are like 101.profit, 102.profit......

Comment: @Singh Sonu, hi, i just have putted the source data preparation in the code, to make you way test it and compare the differences which caused the errors

Comment: @Alexey- i am using two excel file for importing the data.. in that case what will be dd1 and dd2

Comment: in this case you don't need to use dd1 and dd2. dd1 and dd2 needs to prepare the same examples of dataframe. In your case you should compare the dataframe that comes from your excel with datafreme in my examples. I think you should use something like this: df1 = pd.read_excel('filename1.xlsx', index_col = 'Item')
df2 = pd.read_excel('filename2.xlsx', index_col = 'Date')

Comment: in that case i am getting 0rowsx156Col, no values

Comment: if it possible, could you give here the output for both commands: df1.iloc[:2,:].to_dict() and df2.iloc[:2,:].to_dict() or may be just part, like df1.iloc[:2,:10].to_dict() and df1.iloc[:2,:10].to_dict()

Comment: {'Item': {0: 'A', 1: 'B'},
 datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 21, 0, 0): {0: 67, 1: 67},
 datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 22, 0, 0): {0: 67, 1: 67},
 datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 23, 0, 0): {0: 67, 1: 67},
 datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 24, 0, 0): {0: 67, 1: 67},
 datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 25, 0, 0): {0: 68, 1: 68},
 datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 26, 0, 0): {0: 71, 1: 71}} - df1.iloc[:2,:10].to_dict()